# ko postbox request data and communication between ko viewmodels

Tags: knockout.js

Using the library ko postbox it is possible to subscribe to topics and decouple knockout viewmodels. But what if I want to request data between viewmodels. For example get an item by id that is in an array contained in another viewmodel. Is this possible? If not would be the best solutions without using Require JS. A possible option would be to use a master viewmodel to communicate between viewmodels. Is that a good idea?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ko.postbox` does include "normal" pubsub APIs, so it is possible to do a request/response pair. Here is a basic idea where you listen for requests in one view model and send responses with the matches. The other view model initiates the requests and subscribes to the response.

```
var ViewModelOne = function() {
    this.items = ko.observableArray([
        { id: "1", name: "one" },
        { id: "2", name: "two" },
        { id: "3", name: "three" }
    ]);

    this.getItemById = function(id) {
        return id && ko.utils.arrayFirst(this.items(), function(item) {
            return item.id === id
        });
    };

    //listen for requests
    ko.postbox.subscribe("item.request", function(id) {
        //publish a response
        ko.postbox.publish("item.response", this.getItemById(id));
    }, this);
};

var ViewModelTwo = function() {
    this.id = ko.observable().publishOn("item.request");
    this.item = ko.observable().subscribeTo("item.response");
};
```

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/x4nBr/

A couple additional notes/thoughts:

- I don't personally like to pub/sub objects around that can be modified on either side, although it is perfectly valid to do so. I would probably create a copy of the object that I am passing like `ko.toJS(responseData)`
- when doing request/response like this, if there could be multiple subscribers/publishers involved, then you may want to get more complex with your topics (temporarily subscribe on a unique response topic like `item.response.xxxx`, then dispose of the subscription when a response comes back).  Here is a sample that uses the id, but it would be fine to use a unique identifier too: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/2Ycs3/

Comment: Hmm, I think event aggregation should be used for state change only and for data use classic dependency injection or similar. Just my two cents

Comment: @Anders - I do agree. I don't necessarily like passing actual "data" around in this manner.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I will be either using this or writing a custom injector since Require JS is not an option.